# Error on recording UTF8 string with Datasnap

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, delphi-10.3-rio

Recently i've migrated from D2007 to 10.3.3 and i'm having the issue below.

I have a TClientDataSet that record data an encrypted string into .cds format, by storing it in a TStringField and using the *.saveToFile* method. Problem is, the string is not being record correclty into the CDS table.

Here my encrypt function :

```
function encrypt(const ent: string): string;
var m, i, k : integer;
r, s : string;
begin
m := 3;
r := '';
for I := 1 to Length(ent) do
  begin
  k := ord(ent[i]);
  s := chr(k+m);
  r := r + s;
  inc(m);
  end;
result := r;
end;
```

And here is my decrypt function :

```
function decrypt(const ent: string): string;
var m, i,j,K : integer;
r, s : string;
begin
m := 3;
r := '';
s := ent;
for I := 1 to length(s) do
  begin
  if ord(s[i]) < 68 then j := 1 else
    j := -1;
  k := ord(s[i]);
  r := r + chr(k-m);
  inc(m);
  end;
result := r;
end;
```

Now i want to call this function with the string 'engajamento1234'. 
Here is how the watch shows the encrypted string  :

[image]

And here is how the string is actually inserted into the TStringField column of the table :

[image]

Because the string end up being insert incorrectly on the clientdataset, when i call decrypt function with 'hrlgqivoy?|?ACE' string, i get the incorrect original string as 'engajamen3o1234'...

Seems like this problem is related to UTF8 support in the new Delphi version, which the old version did not have.

What i need to do to the string record correctly into the clientdataset and the .cds file, so i get the correct decrypted string back ?

Comment: What the Watch windows show is no real help without knowing what the data is actually supposed to be.  You should add a code example showing data being inserted into the CDS and being read from it.  Perhaps what you are saying is that CDS data saved to disk using D2007 is not read correctly using Rio?

Comment: The data is supposed to be as the first watch shows ; the second is replacing the #$0080 for a ?

Comment: The problem is only on Rio : it saves the data incorrectly.

Comment: When you do CDS.SaveToFile, what TPacketDataFormat are you using?  I still think you need a code example which demonstrates the problem, btw.

Comment: Ok, i just updated the question with the actual code i'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've expanded your code into an MRE which illustrates the problem you are having and how to
solve it.  Basically it seems that the string field you are using to store the encrypted data
is a TStringField, whereas it needs to be a TWideStringField to work with Unicode.  TStringField's
SetAsString and GetAsString methods both use calls which treat the data as an ANSIString (which is the type of Delphi string which predates the introduction of Unicode).

The code uses a conditional define, UseWideString, which determines whether the CDS field is of type ftString (as was used in D2007) or ftWideString, which is the Unicode equivalent.  You should find that with the UseWideString define in effect, the code executes without error,
meaning that the decrypted string is the same as the original input.  If you comment out the
UseWideString define, the

```
Assert(sInput = sDecrypted);
```

fails.

Code

```
program EncryptTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, db, dbclient;

function encrypt(const ent: string): string;
var m, i, k : integer;
r, s : string;
begin
m := 3;
r := '';
for I := 1 to Length(ent) do
  begin
  k := ord(ent[i]);
  s := chr(k+m);
  r := r + s;
  inc(m);
  end;
result := r;
end;

function decrypt(const ent: string): string;
var m, i,j,K : integer;
r, s : string;
begin
m := 3;
r := '';
s := ent;
for I := 1 to length(s) do
  begin
  if ord(s[i]) < 68 then j := 1 else
    j := -1;
  k := ord(s[i]);
  r := r + chr(k-m);
  inc(m);
  end;
result := r;
end;

var
  sInput,
  sEncrypted,
  sDecrypted : String;
  CDS : TClientDataSet;
  Field : TField;

begin
  CDS := TClientDataSet.Create(Nil);

{.$define UseWideString}
{$ifdef UseWideString}
  Field := TWideStringfield.Create(Nil);
{$else}
  Field := TStringfield.Create(Nil);
{$endif}
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.Size := 80;
  Field.FieldName := 'Something';
  Field.DataSet := CDS;

  CDS.CreateDataSet;
  CDS.Append;
  CDS.Edit;

  sInput := 'engajamento1234';
  sEncrypted := encrypt(sInput);
  Field.AsString := sEncrypted;
  sDecrypted := decrypt(Field.AsString);
  Assert(sInput = sDecrypted);

  CDS.Cancel;
  Field.Free;
  CDS.Free;

end.
```

Btw, in your `decrypt` function, the

```
if ord(s[i]) < 68 then j := 1 else
  j := -1;
```

is superfluous because the value of `j` is never used.